# Rice-like Theorems

Tags: computability-theory

Let $\varphi$ be an acceptable programming system. Consider the set $S=\{x\in\mathbb{N}:\varphi_x=\varphi_{x+1}\}$. By using Rogers' Fixed Point Theorem (RFPT) it can be proved that $S$ is a non-recursive set, as follows. Suppose that $S$ is recursive. Then the function $f=\lambda x\mathord{\boldsymbol{.}}(\mu y)(y\geq x\wedge y\notin S)+1$ turns out to be a recursive function and hence by RFPT there exists an index $n$ such that $\varphi_n=\varphi_{f(n)}$: this is a contradiction since we have that $(\forall x)(\varphi_x\neq\varphi_{f(x)})$ (by the definition of $f$). Hence $S$ cannot be recursive. Now, by using similar arguments it can also be proved that, e.g., the set $T=\{x\in\mathbb{N}:\varphi_x\subseteq\varphi_{x+1}\}$ is non-recursive too (here we identify the function $\varphi_y$ with its graph), but the construction of the corresponding function $f$ is a bit more involved than above. Is there a simple and ''uniform'' way (e.g., a sort of ''Rice-like theorem'') to prove the non-recursiveness of sets like $S$ and $T$? It is interesting to observe that the set $\{x\in\mathbb{N}:W_x=W_{x+1}\}$ is non-recursive (where $W_y$ is the domain of the function $\varphi_y$), whereas the recursiveness of $\{x\in\mathbb{N}:W_x\subseteq W_{x+1}\}$ depends on the particular acceptable programming system $\varphi$.

Comment: The proof of Rice's theorem is not at all simpler than the fixed-point theorem you refer to. Why precisely are you unhappy with your proof?